# Creating 3d Numpy array by looping through and appending new 2d Numpy array to it

Tags: python, numpy

I initially had a 3d numpy array of arr_3d of (85, 150, 150) dimension (float values) referred to as original_npy_3d (85 layers, and 150 grids in x and 150 grids in y direction).

I converted it to 2d arr(0, 150, 150) (the first layer) to perform some operation and modify the data in 2D. Now, I would like to repeat the same operation on every layer (0 or rather 1 to 85) and then convert everything back to the original size (85, 150, 150). Is there a way in Python to do that?

```
arr_3d = np.empty((85, 150, 150), float)

for item in range(85):

    arr= original_npy_3d[item,:,:]

    #some operation on arr of the size (150, 150)

    return arr_3d #with all of the generated arr for every layer appended to it
```

Comment: `arr_3d[i,:,:] = arr2d` can be used to assign the values of a (150,150) array to the `i` plane of `arr_3d`.  `original_npy_3d[item,:,:]` is a (150,150) 2d array, not a (0,150,150).  `original_npy_ed[[item],:,:]` returns a (1,150,150), a copy, but usually you don't need to use that.